# Jade Template HTML Bracket Apostrophe and Multiline Issues

Tags: node.js, pug

There's a couple of issues I'm experiencing when I use the `#[]` syntax for HTML tags.

Here's the two issues I'm experiencing:

1. Using an apostrophe

   ```
   p.
       #[strong John's strong text] is really strong.
   ```

   Error message:

   `The end of the string was reached with no closing bracket found.]`
2. Using multiple lines

   ```
   p.
       #[strong This strong text is really really long. This strong
       text is really really long. This strong text is really really
       long.]
   ```

   Error message:

   `The end of the string was reached with no closing bracket found.]`

I've tried solving both problems by adding `\` but no luck.

Comment: The problem is the apostrophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody stumbling on this, I've opened up an issue on Jade's GitHub because it turns out both 1 and 2 are currently not supported.

Link:  https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1723

Answer (score 1):

You can replace ' with

```
&apos;
```

to get rid of the error. So to answer 1. you could do

```
#[strong John&apos;s strong text] and it should work as expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 2021 update

According to [GitHub issue #1723](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1723):

- Case 1 was a bug that has been fixed in Pug 2.0.0 (released in 2018).
- Case 2 is intentional because "it's really not clear exactly what that would mean in terms of indentation." This is suggested as an alternative:

  ```
  p
    strong.
      This strong text is really really long. This strong
      text is really really long. This strong text is really really
      long.
  ```